# Getting 500 Internal Server Error on JAVA but 200 with Node

Tags: javascript, java, rest, https, server

Can someone assist.

I am currently working on a project and working with some APIs.

I have two identical codes Java and Node(Javascript)

Both of the codes were working fine before but suddenly the Java one is now returning a status code 500 while the Node one returns 200.

**Here is the Successful one in Node:**

**POST http://localhost:3001/pay**

**Network**
address: "::1"
family: "IPv6"
port: 3001

**Request Headers**
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: c3a4c3e4-8619-4d00-b1f0-5d32f0e65890
Host: localhost:3001
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 71

**Response Headers**
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 693
ETag: W/"2b5-crRygc3ceDh/mgZoQAOuLBQoVsc"
Date: Fri, 03 Jun 2022 08:42:47 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

**This is the one failing Java:**

**POST http://localhost:8090/pay**

**Network**
address: "::1"
family: "IPv6"
port: 8090

**Request Headers**
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 88453221-ab41-4b51-843b-3022a5db571a
Host: localhost:8090
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 71

**Response Headers**
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 03 Jun 2022 08:43:19 GMT
Connection: close

**Response Body**
{"timestamp":"2022-06-03T08:43:19.971+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","path":"/pay"}

Please note the request headers and body is the same for both projects.

Comment: Redirect Java and NodeJs through a proxy like Mitmproxy, Burp, Charles or Fiddler and compare the requests, then you will see the differences.

Comment: 500 Internal server error means there's exception in your java service, try to take a look at the logging and see what happened.